# How standard android gallery app does "Sharing"?

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-contentresolver, android-sharing

I want to share my video to other apps. Some of them like Instargam, Skype receive it successfully, but others ( WeChat, Line ) show "Unresolved error". I share like that:

```
 val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getString(R.string.provider), File(filePath))
 val shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
                .setType(context.contentResolver.getType(fileUri))
                .setStream(fileUri)
                .intent
```

So the bottle neck is MIME-type, I use this code for auto setting it, and it sets "video/mp4". But apps named above don't recognize this scheme.

When I use standard gallery app, press "share", everything goes well. 
**So I wonder, how does standard app operates this action ?**
And I need to implement my sharing exactly as it made in gallery app.
Can anyone please show me the way?:)

Thanks everyone for answers in advance!